# Determine number of USB controllers on a PC

Tags: usb, device-manager

I need to determine how many individual USB 3 controllers/buses are on a PC. The PC in question is a [Gigabyte Brix GB-BXi7H-5500](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5326#sp).

I plan to use this with a Microsoft Kinect v2 sensor, which is a USB 3 device and [needs to be on its own USB controller](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/sensor_setup.aspx). If there are multiple USB 3 controllers in the PC, I would like to be able to plug in an external USB 3 hard disk as well - but I want to make sure that this doesn't interfere with the Kinect.

The PC in question runs Windows 8.1. I've checked in Device Manager under 'Universal Serial Bus controllers' and I see the following:
[image: Screenshot of Device Manager with the USB controllers node expanded]

But I'm not sure how to interpret this in terms of separate controllers/buses. Is there a way to know for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single USB3.0 controller - the "USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller".

According to [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/8-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.html) (Page 48 of the document):

> The PCH contains one eXtensible Host Controller Interface (xHCI) controller and two Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) controllers. The xHCI controller is mapped as PCI D20:F0 and it supports up to 14 USB 2.0 ports of which 6 can be configured as SuperSpeed (USB 3.0) ports.
>
> EHCI controller 1 (EHCI1) is located at D29:F0 and it supports up to 8 USB 2.0 ports. 
> EHCI controller 2 (EHCI2) is located at D26:F0 and it supports up to 6 USB 2.0 ports.

Comment: Thanks. So in future, if I want to find the number of controllers on a given PC, I should just look for the number of 'Host Controller' entries under the USB node?